# Graph Theory - Triangles

Tags: graph-theory, triangles

This is a question taken from some notes, and I do not know how to solve it, nor I know how to start. Can anyone help me?

Prove that $|E| \geq \lfloor \frac{|V|}{2} \rfloor ^2 $ implies the graph $G$ has at least one triangle.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Great

Comment: Mantel's theorem, but you've stated it incorrectly. $|E|\gt\left\lfloor\frac{|V|^2}4\right\rfloor$ implies $G=(V,E)$ has a triangle.

Comment: As a counterexample to your erroneous statement of Mantel's theorem, consider a graph with $|V|=3$ and $|E|=2.$